# How to convert IEnumerable to IObservable using HistoricalScheduler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IEnumerable<T>` where T allows derivation of a relevant timestamp.

I would like to convert that to an `IObservable<T>` but I wish to use the `HistoricalScheduler` so that notifications occur as per the derived timestamp. Doing this allows use of built-in RX methods for windowing, sliding windows, etc., which are ultimately what I am trying to utilise.

Many of the suggestions of how to go about this suggest using `Generate()`. However, this [method causes StackOverflowExceptions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/103). E.g.:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 2000000);
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var scheduler = new HistoricalScheduler(now);
        var observable = Observable.Generate(
            enumerable.GetEnumerator(), 
            e => e.MoveNext(), 
            e => e, 
            e => Timestamped.Create(e, now.AddTicks(e.Current)), 
            e => now.AddTicks(e.Current), 
            scheduler);
        var s2 = observable.Count().Subscribe(eventCount => Console.WriteLine("Found {0} events @ {1}", eventCount, scheduler.Now));
        scheduler.Start();
        s2.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This will result in a stack overflow.

The standard `ToObservable()` method cannot be used because, although it allows a custom scheduler to be specified, it does not provide any mechanism to control how the resulting notifications are scheduled on that scheduler.

How do I convert an `IEnumerable` to an `IObservable` with explicity scheduled notification?

#### UPDATE

Attempted to use Asti's code in the following test:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 2000000);
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var series = enumerable.Select(i => Timestamped.Create(i, now.AddSeconds(i)));
        var ticks = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(i => now.AddSeconds(i));
        var scheduler = new HistoricalScheduler(now);
        Playback(series,ticks,scheduler).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        scheduler.Start();
    }
```

However it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: time

   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.VirtualTimeSchedulerBase`2.AdvanceTo(TAbsolute time)
   at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Timer.TimerImpl.Tick(Int64 count)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<SchedulePeriodic>b__1()
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.AsyncLock.Wait(Action action)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<SchedulePeriodic>b__0()
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.PeriodicTimer.Tick(Object state)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

Answer (score 5):

We make an operator which replays an ordered sequence of events on a historical scheduler with the time moving according to a specified observable.

```
    public static IObservable<T> Playback<T>(
        this IEnumerable<Timestamped<T>> enumerable,
        IObservable<DateTimeOffset> ticks,
        HistoricalScheduler scheduler = default(HistoricalScheduler)
    )
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
        {
            scheduler = scheduler ?? new HistoricalScheduler();

            //create enumerator of sequence - we're going to iterate through it manually
            var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();

            //set scheduler time for every incoming value of ticks
            var timeD = ticks.Subscribe(scheduler.AdvanceTo);

            //declare an iterator 
            Action scheduleNext = default(Action);
            scheduleNext = () =>
            {
                //move
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    //no more items
                    //sequence has completed
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                    return;
                }

                //current item of enumerable sequence
                var current = enumerator.Current;

                //schedule the item to run at the timestamp specified
                scheduler.ScheduleAbsolute(current.Timestamp, () =>
                {
                    //push the value forward
                    observer.OnNext(current.Value);

                    //schedule the next item
                    scheduleNext();                        
                });
            };

            //start the process by scheduling the first item
            scheduleNext();

            //dispose the enumerator and subscription to ticks
            return new CompositeDisposable(timeD, enumerator);
        });
    }
```

Porting your earlier example,

```
   var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 20000000);
            var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            var series = enumerable.Select(i => Timestamped.Create(i, now.AddSeconds(i)));
            var ticks = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(i => now.AddSeconds(i));

            series.Playback(ticks).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

We read through the enumerable to keep it lazy, and set the clock with a simple `Interval` observable. Reducing the interval causes it to playback faster.

Comment: Thanks Asti. Struggling to get my head around what's going on here. If I pass `ticks` parameter as `null` it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt if you pass in ticks as null, nothing will happen at all because the scheduler will not advance in time. When you run the sample you should be getting the expected output of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: Added comments for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Phil,
I think you will find problems regardless if you try to issue a notification every tick. Rx just wont be able to keep up.

I see what @asti is doing here, But I think it can made a touch simpler using what Paul already had (`IEnumerable<Timestamped<T>>`)

```
public static IObservable<T> Playback<T>(
   this IEnumerable<Timestamped<T>> enumerable,
   IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();

        //declare a recursive function 
        Action<Action> scheduleNext = (self) =>
        {
            //move
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                //no more items (or we have been disposed)
                //sequence has completed
                scheduler.Schedule(()=>observer.OnCompleted());
                return;
            }

            //current item of enumerable sequence
            var current = enumerator.Current;

            //schedule the item to run at the timestamp specified
            scheduler.Schedule(current.Timestamp, () =>
            {
                //push the value forward
                observer.OnNext(current.Value);

                //Recursively call self (via the scheduler API)
                self();
            });
        };

        //start the process by scheduling the recursive calls.
        // return the scheduled handle to allow disposal.
        var scheduledTask = scheduler.Schedule(scheduleNext);
        return StableCompositeDisposable.Create(scheduledTask, enumerator);
    });
}
```

This is also scheduler agnostic so will work with any scheduler.